# [RIAK-PHP-CLIENT]: Fetch and display JSON text data on localhost from Riak

Tags: php, json, text, localhost, riak

I have successfully gotten a connection between my riak database and localhost by using the official Basho riak-php-client:

https://github.com/basho/riak-php-client

In my Riak database, I have a lot of keys stored with JSON data. Is there any easy and effective way of displaying the text data on the localhost? So far, I have been able to display simple other values using this code:

```
     <?php

                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Riak.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Bucket.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Exception.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Link.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Object.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/StringIO.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Utils.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/Link/Phase.php');
                require_once('src/Basho/Riak/MapReduce/Phase.php');

                        $client = new Basho\Riak\Riak('172.31.42.72', 10018);

                        $myBucket = $client->bucket('test');
                        $myBucket1 = $client->bucket('world');


                        $val1 = 1;
                        $obj1 = $myBucket-> newObject('one', $val1);
                        $obj1->store();

                        $val2 = 'two';
                        $obj2 = $myBucket->newObject('two', $val2);
                        $obj2->store();

                        $val3 = array('myValue' => 3);
                        $obj3 = $myBucket->newObject('three', $val3);
                        $obj3->store();

                        $fetched1 = $myBucket->get('one');
                        $fetched2 = $myBucket->get('two');
                        $fetched3 = $myBucket->get('three');
                        $fetched4 = $myBucket1->get('542660947589230592');


                        assert($val1 == $fetched1->getData());
                        assert($val2 == $fetched2->getData());
                        assert($val3 == $fetched3->getData());

                        $obj = json_decode(fetched4);
                        print $obj->{'<<"text">>'};


           ?>
```

In this code I have also tried to display the JSON data which is in the variable $fetched4, and queried from the bucket 'world', but when I try and display it with these two lines of code:

```
 $obj = json_decode(fetched4);
 print $obj->{'<<"text">>'};
```

Nothing is displayed. Any ideas?

EDIT

Here are the apache2 error logs although I am not entierly sure if they're fully up-to-date:

> [Wed Dec 10 14:05:20.894220 2014] [:error] [pid 4610] [client
>   129.16.723.16:44285] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant fetched4 - assumed 'fetched4' in /var/www/html/index.php on line 52
>
> [14:05:20.894240 2014] [:error] [pid 4610] [client 129.16.723.16:44285]
>   PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 53[Wed Dec 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try...

```
 $obj = json_decode($fetched4);
```

Unless it was a typo in entering your example here, you're missing the `$` on `$fetched4`.

The log entry `PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant fetched4 - assumed 'fetched4'` points to it being a real problem and not just something you've done here though.

Comment: Ah, but of course. I made some additional changes because I was still getting warnings and notices, so now my PHP code basically consists of:

$client = new Basho\Riak\Riak('172.31.42.72', 10018);
                   $jsondata = $client->bucket('world');
                   $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
                   echo $json['542660947589230592'][0]['text'];

Comment: still getting this error:

[Thu Dec 11 13:36:53.590991 2014] [:error] [pid 4611] [client 129.16.233.32:39014] PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 29

Comment: It's hard to see your code in the comments above, but it looks like you're stuffing a bucket into `$jsondata` rather than fetching the value you want from that bucket by its key?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that along the way as well but I am still getting the same error:    "PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/index.php on line 33
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/index.php on line 35"

Comment: Apologies for code being difficult to read, kind of new here and I have difficulty formatting my comments haha. The code: 

`$myBucket = $client->bucket('world');

                        $fetched = $myBucket->get('542660947589230592');

                        $result = json_decode($fetched, true);  
                        foreach ($result['data'] as $tweet) {
                         echo $tweet['text'], '<br>';

                       }`

Comment: Seems like you need to do a little debugging and work what you actually have in `$fetched` and `$result`.

Comment: @Jazzbaron If my answer was good for your original question, please accept this answer so that people with the similar problems find it easier, thanks.